# Flutter: How to pass data from the parent stateful widget to one of the tabs in the BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen();

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    MapsScreen(),
    HistoryScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    RestAPI.loadMapsFromNetwork();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home screen'),
      ),
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped, // new
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.map),
            title: new Text('Maps'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.change_history),
            title: new Text('History'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

This home.dart makes a network call in initState method.
How do I pass the list of maps that the client received from the network to one of the tabs like MapsScreen? Do I need to use ScopedModel or InheritedWidget or is there a better approach? All the logic to render is within the MapsScreen class.

Comment: You can also use stream for sending some data. Is this better or worse - I don't know. It depends on your code and your goals

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value from the json response like this.

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget { 
Map<List<String,dynamic>> data ;

MapScreen({this.data}) ;

  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState() ;

 }

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> { 
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Container( 
       child: ListView( 
         /* use the data over here */ 
       ), 
    ); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: My question is around passing the response obtain from the network request made from the Homescreen to the one of tabs screen.